# Will stopping django-haystack rebuild_index command in the middle ruin the whole index?

Tags: elasticsearch, django-haystack

If I stop the `rebuild_index` process now will the whole index be ruined or will it still work with all the documents it has indexed so far?

I'm indexing all of wikipedia in haystack and it seems to be exponentially slowing down around the 3 million document mark.  I would like to stop it and use what I've indexed so far but want to know if there's a way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stopping the `rebuild_index` process will not ruin anything. Your index will just not contain the full dataset, but anything that has been bulk-indexed so far will be available and searchable.